# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'financials_api_get' when trying to run folder location

Tags: python, pathlib

I have a folder directory that looks as such:

```
-- show_case
  --airflow
    --dags
      fundamental_data_pipeline.py
  __init__.py
  financials_api_get.py
```

I am trying to run a function `get_fundemental_data` from `financial_api_get.py` within `fundamental_data_pipeline.py` but I get an import error.

My file `fundamental_data_pipeline.py` looks like this:

```
sys.path.insert(1, Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent)
print(Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent)
from financials_api_get import get_fundemental_data
```

A print of the path prints `show_case` but I still get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'financials_api_get'
```

Why doesn't this work?

EDIT
I have an `__init__.py` file that looks as such:

```
from financials_api_get import get_fundemental_data
```

Comment: you have char `s` in word `financials` in `from financials_api_get ...` but filename is without `s` - `financial_api_get.py`

Comment: @furas Sorry was a typo in the question

Comment: maybe it treats it as internal module and it needs file `__init__.py`. Do you get `show_case` or `/full/path/to/show_case` ?

Comment: @furas Edited the question as I have an init file that I forgot to add in the original question. The error is: "/full/path/to/show_case\airflow\dags\fundamental_data_pipeline.py", line 11, in <module>
    from financials_api_get import get_fundemental_data
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'financials_api_get'

Comment: you may check if file really exists `print( os.listdir( Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent ) )`

Comment: I tested code and accidently get I found that I have the same problem when I have `symlink` in path (on Linux). I need `os.path.realpath()` to get real path. `p = os.path.realpath( Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent )` and later I can do `sys.path.insert(0, p)` and it works.

Comment: when I use `print()` to see `Path(__file__).resolved()` then I see it create wrong path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is `Path` because `sys.path` expects only `strings`.

If you run `print(sys.path)` then you should see `[Path(...), ...]`

So you may need `str()`

```
p = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent

sys.path.insert(0, str(p) )
```

or `.as_posix()`

```
p = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent

sys.path.insert(0, p.as_posix() )
```